# Sharing function through classes in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I don't get one basic thing. How to share functions through folders, files and classes using Kotlin. I want to let my function hide_bar(), start in another class.

Theme.kt (located inside a folder)

```
class theme : AppCompatActivity()
{
    fun hide_bars() {
        window.decorView.apply {
            systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        }
    }
}
```

Dock.kt

```
class dock : AppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.dock)
        hide_bar()
    }
}
```

Please help me with this code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an extension fun (directly in a file, not inside any class or object):

```
fun Activity.hideBars() {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
}
```

...then just call:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.dock)
    hideBars()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this

your static functions need to be in the companion part

```
class theme 
{
    companion {
        fun hide_bars(window:Window) {
            window.decorView.apply {
                systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            }
        }
    }
}

class dock : AppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.dock)
        theme.hide_bar(window)
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't call hide_bar directly, instead you should call `theme.hide_bar(window)`